# How do I separate unique and duplicate items from two arrays in perl?

Tags: arrays, perl, duplicates, unique

I have this program and I think I'm close but I can't figure out where to go from here.  I have entered the loop where I am currently trying to get rid of duplicate numbers from the unique array and enter them into the duplicate array.  I think I need to use a hash but am unsure on how to go about it.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
while ($second != -1){
    $second = <STDIN>;
    chomp $second;
    @second[$j] = $second;
    @unique[$j+$i-1] = $second;
    while($x<10){
        if($second == @unique[$x]){
            @duplicate[$x]=$second;
            pop @unique;
        }
        $x++;
    }
    $x=0;
    $j++;
}
pop @second;
pop @unique;
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do the job:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @original = qw/foo bar hello world foo bar f00 bar barr/; # = array with input data
my %uniques;
my @dupes = grep $uniques{$_}++, @original;

print "unique:    ";
print join ', ', keys %uniques; # output unique elements

print "\nduplicate: ";
print join ', ', @dupes; # output duplicate elements
```

Output:

```
unique:    foo, barr, hello, f00, world, bar
duplicate: foo, bar , bar
```

Explanation:

With `grep` you look at each array element in `@original`. Each element (temporary placed in `$_`) is inserted into the hash `%uniques` as a key. A hash doesn't allow to have multiple keys with the same name in it, so that's how you get rid of the duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Below program will iterate over `@original` and will make two new arrays, each for unique and duplicate respectively. Duplicate will contain the element `n` times, if its repeated `n` times in array.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @original = qw/foo bar hello world foo bar f00 bar barr/; # = array with input data

my %hash = ();
map {$hash{$_}++} @original;
my (@uniques, @duplicates) = ((), ());
for my $key (keys %hash) {
    if ($hash{$key} == 1) {
        push (@uniques, $key);
    } else {
        push (@duplicates, $key) for (1..$hash{$key});
    }
}
print "@uniques\n";
print "=============\n";
print "@duplicates\n";
```